# Using Filter Formula with Named Ranges across Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic named range that I use and I am looking into using the filter function to reduce that data down on another worksheet using references to criteria on that new worksheet.

`=FILTER(Loss_Run, ULGTACCT Code = $B$2,"")`

**ULGTACCT** is the column name,

**$B$2** will have a number stored as text

**Loss_Run** is dynamic named range that is an indirect formula (This could be the cause of my headache)

Online I found If its named I can just reference the name of the range and columns by name but since its a formula will that not work?

Update
`=FILTER('Loss Template'!A:M, 'Loss Template'!A:A = $B$2,"")`

The formula directly above references a "printout" of the named range that is used in workbook and if I hardcode the value for B2 it works but it does not work if i try to reference B2.

**Note:** It would be kinda difficult to mock up **Loss_Run** because of the nature of the range being a complicated indirect().

Comment: please post some links to photos so we can see what you are doing.  Also the exact formula you are trying.  It is very hard to find errors without all the information. If you need to, mock up the data.

Comment: @ScottCraner is that better?

Comment: is B2 a number or text?  `VALUE($B$2)` will return an error if it is text that is not possible to convert to a number.

Comment: it is a formula that returns a number

Comment: Then there is the possibility that your data to which you are trying to match are numbers stored as text.

Comment: You know what that might be true. so how do I format a spill range?

Comment: What if I change B2 to Text would that help?

Comment: @ScottCraner in changing the above formula and the cell B2 to be formatted as text I get the #NAME? error.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation in Google Sheets though I don't have the complexity of a dynamic named range. I ended up using something like this.

```
=FILTER(Loss_Run, INDEX(Loss_Run,,1) = $B$2,"")
```

The INDEX function properly brought out the column I need to test against for the FILTER.

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the text function to the criteria range.

```
    =FILTER('Loss Template'!A:M, 'Loss Template'!A:A=TEXT($B$2,"0"),"Still Not 
    Working")
```

The issue was the target range was numbers as text and just formatting the criteria cell as text was not enough.